# integer variable used with fgetc()

Tags: c++, c, pointers, for-loop, fgetc

I was trying to understand some basic code and got slightly confused by following code

```
int main ()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int c;
   int n = 0;

   fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error in opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   do
   {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if ( feof(fp) )
      {
         break ;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
   } while(1);

   fclose(fp);
   return(0);
}
```

Can someone explain me why c is of type integer, even though it is defined by `fgetc(fp)` which, from my knowledge, gets just the next character?

Comment: Look again at [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc), it returns an `int` (with good reason), so assigning that result to an `int` is also a good idea.

Comment: `c` is of type `int`, not "integer". The word "integer" covers all the integer types, from `char` up to `long long` (and their unsigned variants).

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3185968

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the precise way this particular code has been written, `c` wouldn't need to be of type `int`--it would still work if `c` were of type `char`.

Most code that reads characters from a file should (at least initially) read those characters into an `int` though. Specifically, part of the basic design of C-style I/O is that functions like `getc` and `fgetc` can return EOF in addition to any value that could have come from the file. That is to say, any value of type `char` could be read from the file. `getc`, `fgetc`, etc., can signal the end of file by returning at least one value that *won't*/*can't* have come from the file. It's usually -1, but that's not guaranteed. When `char` is signed (which it usually is, nowadays) you can get a value from the file that will show up as -1 when it's been assigned to a `char`, so if you're depending on the return value to detect EOF, this can lead to mis-detection.

The code you've included in the question simply copies the contents of the file to standard output, one character at a time. Making use of the EOF return value, we can simplify the code a little bit, so the main loop looks like this:

```
int c;

while (EOF != (c = fgetc(fp)))
    printf("%c", c); // or: putchar(c);
```

I suppose some might find this excessively terse. Others may object to the assignment inside the condition of the loop. I, at least, think those are reasonable and valid arguments, but this still fits enough better with the design of the library that it's preferable.

Comment: OP's `c = fgetc(fp); if ( feof(fp) )` well handles the rare situation of `unsigned char` and `int` having the same number of unique values.  `while (EOF != (c = fgetc(fp)))` is a common idiom, but not superior to OP's

Comment: @chux: That situation is not merely rare--it's completely unheard of (i.e., a purely theoretical possibility). At the same time, the code in question is significantly more difficult to read (especially for somebody accustomed to C, for whom the idiomatic code is immediately recognizable. In other words, it exchanges a purely theoretical advantage for a completely real disadvantage.

Comment: Analog Devices 32-bit SHARC DSP.  As somebody well accustomed to C, I do not find `c = fgetc(fp); if ( feof(fp) )` significantly more difficult to read.  I doubt any recent/mew machine will have `INT_MAX-IINT_MIN == UCHAR_MAX-UCHAR_MIN`.  I also doubt any machine will not use 2's complement integer, yet C still maintain UB on `int` overflow.  So I code defensively and watch for overflow.  I do not denigrate code like `c = fgetc(fp); if ( feof(fp) )` as needing simplification when it is in fact a reasonable alternative nor object to terse Yoda-like code `EOF != (c = fgetc(fp))`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it possible to use %c with an `int` in printf? You have to specify a type when pulling arguments out of variadic functions, and I thought that printf expects a `char` upon encountering %c. Wouldn't passing an `int` where it expects a `char` lead to undefined behaviour? Or does it just cast it?

Comment: @JoshuaPerrett printf's %c expects an int, not a `char` that is why it is OBVIOUSLY possible.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of [fgetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/)

> int fgetc ( FILE * stream );

And about [return](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/#return) value of `fgetc`

> > On success, the character read is returned (promoted to an int value).
> >     The return type is int to accommodate for the special value `EOF`, which indicates failure.

So we declare variable as integer. As character may be unsigned which can't take negative value. But implementation of `EOF` always negative or very commonly `-1` which can be use as failure or end of file. So it is safe to use integer and can be use like

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
   //Code goes here
}
```

Comment: Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined (C11§6.2.5/15). `EOF` is always negative (C11§7.21.1/3).

Comment: Yes, so it is safe to use integer.

Comment: "As character may be unsigned which can't take negative value." is true, but an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` _can_ have a negative value.  Consider `unsigned char` and `int` both using 32-bit.  Legal in C, but rare.  OP's `c = fgetc(fp); if ( feof(fp) )` is more robust than `int c; while ((c = fgetc(fp))!=EOF){`

Comment: FWIW, I've got a different quote. My manpage says: "`fgetc()`,  `getc()` and `getchar()` return the character read as an _unsigned char_ cast to an _int_ or `EOF` on end of file or error" and I use `getchar` in that way. Values from 0 to 255 indicate valid input, the special value `EOF` indicates the end of the file. `EOF` is negative, so it is distinct from valid input.

Comment: @chux: Your comment is being discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32646556/908515

Comment: @M Oehm `unsigned char` is not limited to 0 to 255, but to `UCHAR_MAX` - although that is certainly common to be 255.  It is not even limited to 0 to `INT_MAX`.  In that rare case, a conversion of `unsigned char` to `int` may result in a negative value equal to `EOF`.  Man pages reflect a large segment of C, but is not the C spec.