# What is the better way to check EOF and error of fgetc()?

Tags: c, fgetc

I always use this approach

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

As it seems to me more readable and robust. But to an answer of mine [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640939/2317535), [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640855/integer-variable-used-with-fgetc/32640939#comment53133141_32640939) commented that

> if ( feof(fp) ) is more robust than
>      int c; while ((c = fgetc(fp))!=EOF)

As

```
    while(1)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if ( feof(fp) )
        {
            break ;
        }
        printf("%c", c);
    }
```

is more robust than the first version. So what version should I use? Please explain me why that version is better.

**EDIT**

In question [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) there asked  why feof() in control  loop always  wrong. But checking `feof()` in if condition in proper way is always wrong? Explanation is appreciable.

Comment: Use the first version.  The second one isn't any “more robust” but it requires much more coding. It also fails to check for an error condition.

Comment: @user - No, the proper C++ way is `while (cin >> c)`, and absolutely **not** `while (!cin.eof())`. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @Kninnug It is not  duplicate of that question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3861506/539810

Comment: The [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640855/integer-variable-used-with-fgetc/32640939#comment53133141_32640939) was not replicated in full and so slants this discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually program input loops like this:

```
int c;

while (c = fgetc(fp), c != EOF) {
    /* do something with c here */
}

/* check if EOF came from an end-of-file or an error */
if (ferror(fp)) {
    /* error handling here */
}
```

You should generally not use a loop condition like this:

```
while (!feof(fp)) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

or

```
for (;;) {
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if (feof(fp))
        break;
}
```

Because this breaks when an IO error is encountered. In this case, `fgetc` returns `EOF` but the end-of-file flag is not set. Your code could enter an infinite loop as an error condition usually persists until external action is taken.

The proper way is to check the result of `fgetc()`: If it's equal to `EOF`, you can usually stop reading further data as both in case of an IO error and an end-of-file condition, it's usually not possible to read further data. You should then check if an error occurred and take appropriate action.

Comment: The OP asked for an *explanation*.

Comment: It is not an useless answer (which should then be downvoted), but doesn't really answer what the OP's looking for.

Answer (score 5):

**2 Interesting Issues**

**`ferror()`**

`ferror()` reflects the state of the *error indicator for the stream*.  This flag is set when a rare input error occurs *and remains set* until cleared - see `clearerr()`.  If a read input errors and code later reads again, *without clearing*, `ferror()` still reports true, even if the following read is not in error.

When `fgetc()` returns `EOF` it could be due to an end-of-file (common) or the rare input error.  Better to check `feof()` than `ferror()` to distinguish.  `ferror()` could be true due a prior error and not the present case - which is certainly end-of-file.

```
int c;
c = fgetc(file);
if (c == EOF) {
  if (feof(file)) puts("end-of-file");
  else puts("input error");
}
```

**Wide `char`**: The issue of testing for an error condition came up because of a [corner case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32641375/2410359) in C.

`fgetc()` returns an `int`.  Its values are in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`, (some negative number).

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
  // do something with ch
}
if (ferror(fp)) Handle_InputError();
if (feof(fp)) Handle_EndOffFile();  // Usually nothing special
```

Yet C allows `unsigned char` to have a wider range than the positive number of `int`.  The converting an `unsigned char` to `int` has an implementation defined behavior which may result in an `unsigned char` value being converted to a negative `int` - and one that matches `EOF`.

Such platforms are rare and not in the main-stream of 2015. Most will have `UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` and the above style is typically used.  Doubtful these platforms will ever become common due to the amount of code, like the above, that relies on `EOF` being distinct from `unsigned char`converted to `int`.

Should code need to handle the rare case where `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`,  then

```
int c;
for (;;)
{
    c = fgetc(file);
    if (c == EOF) {
      if (feof(file)) break;
      if (ferror(file)) break;
      // fall through if both if's fail.
    }
    // do stuff with c
}
```

The popular reference in [while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/2410359) highlights the mistake code often makes in using the results of `fgetc(in)` before checking for problems.  Both codes in other answers check for error conditions before using the result of `fgetc()`.

---

The 2nd code handles all situations including ones that may only apply to a computer sitting in a some long forgotten rubbish heap.  The first is far more common.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested improvement is not better, even less robust.

As is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/908515), it enters an endless loop if a read error happens (without eof). In that case, `feof` would return `0` while `fgetc` returns `EOF`.

Your version does not have this issue.

Besides, your version is shorter, less complex and pretty much standard.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman: It is not a duplicate.